# Tableau_sales calculation 7 days ago

Tags: tableau-api

Could you help me with one question re Sales: now I have the amount of Sales by months, but I also would like to add column to see the amount 7 days ago to compare progress and difference. How could I do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STOIr.png)

Comment: could you please specify what "7 days ago" is referred to?

maybe with some sample data?

Comment: I would like to add last 7 days difference for sales but I show this information by months

Comment: I would like to add last 7 days difference for sales but I show this information by months     November    December. I could calculate delta via look up (ZN(SUM([Value])) - lookup(ZN(SUM([Value])),-1)) but I can't as I need information re last 7 days but I show amount for months. I use parameter to switch from absolute value to 7 days difference. For example:  today December sales = 50 000, but 7 days ago there was an amount 30 000. I would like to calculate this percent difference in tableau